# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net

Hola comunidad de programadores. Les comento mi problema. Tengo una tabla que la quiero llenar con registro de una base de datos, para esto utilizo ajax, pero cuando se ejecuta el javascript para llenar la tabla me sale el error este: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

```
function addRows(data) {
    table = $("#table_id").DataTable();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        table.fnAddData([
            data[i].id,
            data[i].name,
            data[i].description,
            data[i].price,
            data[i].idSector
            //'<button type="button" value="Actualizar" title="Actualizar" class="btn btn-primary"> </button>'
        ]);
    }
}

function sendDataAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        URL: "Articulos.aspx/loadGrid",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            addRows(data.d);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.d)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Si haces un `console.log(data)` ¿Que te muestra en consola? Porque a simple vista el error dice que `length` es null, es decir que no tiene datos. Debes primero asegurarte si data trae o no datos.

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 cosas que pueden estar sucediendo, una es que como data es una variable reservada para ajax puede estar tomando el data que tienes definida como "{}" para solucionar esto prueba cambiando la variable data que le pasas a success por otro valor (result o lo que quieras)

La segunda puede ser que la variable data que se te devuelve en el callback (success) de ajax no tiene compontente .d/esta mal estructurado/no devuelve nada.
Tendrias que revisar logs a consola pues no tenemos la función que te retorna los datos.(console.log)